# How to insert multiple record from SOQL query?

Tags: apex

I have wrote some code for insert multiple record using soql query but when i try to insert record it will only inserting one record not multiple even i have already selected two record.

Class :

```
public PageReference save(){
       PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/InvoiceSummary');

            inv.Billed_Through__c = adList.get(0).Issue__r.Publication__r.Billed_Through__c;
            inv.Invoice_Memo__c = adList.get(0).Issue__r.Publication__r.Name;
            inv.Customer__c = [select Id, Name from Contact where AccountId =: adList.get(0).Contact__r.AccountId limit 1].Id;

            insert inv;

        return pageRef;    
    }
```

'even i have already selected two record' (record is fetch from here)

```
    invList = new List<Invoice__c>([Select Id, Billed_Through__c,Customer__c,Invoice_Memo__c From Invoice__c ]);
    adList = new List<Ad_Order__c>();
    adList = [Select Id,Issue__r.Publication__r.Billed_Through__c,Issue__r.Publication__r.Name,Contact__r.Accountid From Ad_Order__c where id in : adidList limit 10000];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is not bulikified. So  the code executes only for one record.
Pseduo code

```
List<Invoice__c> lstInV = new List<Invoice__c>
for( Contact oContact :  [select Id, Name from Contact where AccountId =:   adList.get(0).Contact__r.AccountId].Id]
{
 lstInV.add(oContact .Id);
}
Database.upsert(lstInV ) ;
```